# Flipping a coin to maximize ratio of heads

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics

You flip a coin with the goal of maximizing the ratio of heads to total flips; you can decide to stop whenever. What is the expected value of this ratio?

My thoughts: The ratio is at least $3/4$. With $1/2$ probability we flip heads first and stop.

Otherwise, we flip until the ratio is $1/2$ (random walks return to the origin with probability $1$) giving an expected ratio of $3/4$. Can we do better?

Comment: This has been asked on Puzzling.SE: [What is the value of this coin flipping game?](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/23126/) A comment suggests that it is an unsolved problem.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140184/expected-ratio-of-coin-flips?rq=1 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6195/why-is-this-coin-flipping-probability-problem-unsolved?noredirect=1&lq=1